# Написать DELETE запрос который будет удалять дочерний элемент в БД json-server

Tags: xmlhttprequest

Есть симуляция БД на json-server:

```
"todos": [
    {
      "id": 1692707819147,
      "name": "admin",
      "columns": [
        {
          "columnId": 1692707826469,
          "columnName": "asd",
          "tasks": [
            "asdsa"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1692826777189,
      "name": "asd",
      "columns": [
        {
          "columnId": 1692826783166,
          "columnName": "asd",
          "tasks": []
        },
        {
          "columnId": 1692828523449,
          "columnName": "asd2",
          "tasks": []
        }
      ]
    }]
```

не могу написать путь, который будет удалять конкретный объект из массива `columns`, к примеру из объекта с айди = 1692826777189:

```
       {
          "columnId": 1692826783166,
          "columnName": "asd",
          "tasks": []
        }
```

Пробовал так:

```
axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/todos/1692826777189/columns/1692826783166`)
```

и много других вариантов, и `_embed` тоже использовал